# Limit To Number Of Post Requests (Javascript + node.js + jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

Basically I have client side javascript which sends post requests (through jQuery) triggered by user interactions with the page to my node.js server.  The node.js server then handles the requests and updates content in the database.

For some reason, I am reaching a limit of the number of posts I can send to the server in a single page load.  This maximum is 6.  After 6 posts are sent from a page, I get these errors for trying to send any more requests:

EDIT:

These red errors are popping up in my Javascript console after trying to send more than 6 requests:

```
    send jquery-latest.js:8526
    jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-latest.js:7978
    jQuery.(anonymous function) jquery-latest.js:7614
    haveLikedOrDislikedObject
    (anonymous function) localhost:33
    fire jquery-latest.js:1037
    self.fireWith jquery-latest.js:1148
    done jquery-latest.js:8074
    callback
```

My code for sending the post: (Basically a listener is attached to numerous divs, and when it is clicked a post request is sent)

```
    //Sets on click listener for like button of content
    $(document).delegate("div[id^='likeDiv']", "click", function() {
        var el = this;
        $.getScript("public/javascripts/load_content.js", function(){
            haveLikedOrDislikedObject(0, $(el).attr('name'), theUser);
        });
    });

    function haveLikedOrDislikedObject(res, contentNumber, user){

        if(user != undefined){
            if(res == 0){
                $.post("/likeContent", { content: contentNumber, user: user.UserID });
                $("#haveLikedDiv_" + contentNumber).text("You like this.");
            } else{
                $.post("/dislikeContent", { content: contentNumber, user: user.UserID });       
                $("#haveLikedDiv_" + contentNumber).text("You dislike this.");
            }
        } else{
            $("#haveLikedDiv_" + contentNumber).text("Sorry, something went wrong.");
        }
    };
```

Just wondering why I would be getting this limit?  Also, any thoughts on how I can go around this, or other ways to send numerous things to my server from a single page?

**SOLVED:**
Turns out I was not sending back anything from my server and I think this means each post was waiting for a response, therefore making 6 open requests.  So, make sure that you are sending something back from the server, even if it is undefined like this:

```
    app.post('/likeContent', function(req, res){
       res.send(undefined);
    });
```

Comment: What errors?  I see no errors in what you have posted.  Post your code for a reproducible example.

Comment: What exactly are "these errors"?

Comment: Why not let the callback function issue another AJAX request? Then you're not firing 6 or more events at the same time, but sequentially.

Comment: They do happen sequentially.  That post method is only triggered when users click on certain elements of the page.  6 requests are not being sent at once.

Comment: Then please post more code or perhaps better, a live demo page so we can reproduce your issue. I cannot make anything of these error messages.

Comment: Maybe the server sends back some `X-RateLimit-Remaining` header or something like that. Please check, if it does.

Comment: No, I am not getting that header.  Also, I have posted more code.

Comment: Please answer your own question in an answer and accept it, so this question gets closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was not sending back anything from my server and I think this means each post was waiting for a response, therefore making 6 open requests. So, make sure that you are sending something back from the server, even if it is undefined like this:

```
app.post('/likeContent', function(req, res){
   res.send(undefined);
});
```